# Polling Java EE background task status - how to?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I'm currently working on a web application which needs to import data and do some processing. This can take some time (probably in the "several minutes" range, once the data sets grow), so we're running it in the background - and now the time has come to show status in the frontend, instead of tailing log files :)

The frontend is using Angular, hooked up to REST endpoints (JAX-RS) calling services in EJBs that do persistance via JPA. Running in JBoss EAP 6.4 / AS 7.5 (EE6). Standard stuff, but this is the first time I'm dealing with Java EE.

With regards to querying status, polling a REST endpoint periodically is fine - we don't need fancy stuff like websockets. We do need to support multiple background jobs, though, and information consisting of runstate (running/done/error), progress and list of errors.

So, I current have two questions:

1) Is there a more suitable way of launching a background task than calling a @Asynchronous EJB method?

2) Which options do I have for keeping track of the background tasks, and which is most suitable?

My first idea was to keep a HashMap, but that quckly ended up looking like too much manual (and fragile-looking) code with concurrency and lifetime concerns - and I prefer not reinventing the wheel. The safe choice seems to be JPA persisting it, but that seems somewhat clumsy for volatile status information.

I'm obviously not the first person facing these issues, but my google-fu seems to be lacking at the moment :)

Comment: What kind of tracking info do you need for your processes?

Comment: I'd like to be able to associate a background task with an instance of a custom State class - necessary information is mentioned in the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks could be launched using `@Asynchronous` or by using JMS `@MessageDriven`

From java-ee-7 [ManagedExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) is also an option.

The tasks would then update their own state that is stored in a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/singleton_the_perfect_cache_facade) inside a `@Singleton` EJB.

If you are in a clustered environment, state of tasks is better stored using JPA, as @Singleton is not for whole cluster

Comment: I tried implementing a solution with @Singleton, but broke re-entrancy - I'll try fixing it when I have more time, but for now JPA seems the safe bet.

Comment: what did your singleton class look like? that should be avoidable

Comment: The singleton problem turned out to be missing @ConcurrencyManagement annotations. Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Im curious what you had to add, can u add an example?

Comment: You can either add @Lock annotations (READ or WRITE) to methods to let the container manage synchronization, or use @ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN) to handle all synchronization yourself - which is the better choice when using concurrent data structures, since you avoid creating an unnecessary Lock that way.